# variable visible from diferrent jsp pages

Tags: jsp

> Hello!  i have this problem... i have a for-loop in my jsp which generates  buttons

```
<div class=button>
     <% for (int i=0; i<2; i++ ) { %>
     //Title button is Title i.
     //Each button send the user at the same url destination.jsp`
</div>
```

> So in the user appears **[Title 1]  [Title 2]** When i am in the *destination.jsp* how can i know the value of i? thanxs a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="CardDetailForm.jsp?param='"+i+"'"></a>
```

Comment: doesn't work..  the page is a jsp...
then how i will retrieve the value of i?

Comment: ok i wrote this and it works
`<a href="CardDetailForm.jsp?param=<%=i%>" >`

now in the next page how i get the i?

Comment: you can use request.getParameter("param");